# Getting Started with Python YQL

Tags: python, yql

I want to try to use the Yahoo Fantasy Sports API for my fantasy football  league, but it seems like I can only access the data if I authenticate with Yahoo.  Makes sense.  However, I am new to Python and have no idea how to get started.

I found a python module on the web
[link text](https://launchpad.net/python-yql/+download)
but I don't know how to "install" a file that has a .gz extension on a windows machine.

Simply, any help you can provide on how to use oauth with yahoo in python will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: just download it, extract it and go to the location of setup.py in the extracted directory and run setup.py install command. It will get installed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment,but I did try that to no avail.  I used dos-prompt and attempted to build then install similar to other packages with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use easysinstall

> c:/python25/scripts/easy_install.exe yql

Replace path with your computer's python path if necessary.